# Multiplying/dividing mean and std dev of two different values

Tags: statistics

I'm working on predicting outcomes of games given statistics from the two teams involved. Two of the statistics I have are below:

AGA (average goals against):
The arithmetic mean of number of goals a team's opponent scored in each game.

AOP (average offensive production):
The geometric mean of (the ratio between the number of goals a team scored and their opponent's AGA in each game).

Now I have two teams, A and B, that have not played each other, but may have played zero or more of the same teams. A simple way to predict the number of goals scored by A against B is to multiply A's AOP by B's AGA. Is there a way to get a standard deviation of this predicted outcome from the numbers given? What if I had the values averaged to give the AGA and AOP in question?

Could the same be done for division between two statistics instead of multiplication?